# Routing to same page/component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem, in my application after submitting a form it will ask for do you want to add one more item? and have 2 options "yes" or "no".If the user selecting no he will route to dash board and Yes he should stay there in the same page.I have tried it

``

```
  <input type="button" value="Yes" class="button small" @click="$router.go()" /> ``
```

its working fine normal but on deployment showing 404-not available.

In such situation to route in same page what we have to do?

It will be very helpful why its happening and what will be the solution for that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to render your form based on a value and when the user clicks on 'yes' button, you add to the value and actually another form renders, there is no need to call a router.go method.

Comment: thank you,,can you show me an example how to render a form based on a value,at this moment it will be helpful

Comment: Think about an array like form_counter=[1]. Then consider your tag form rendering so: <form v-for="counter in form_counter"> ... each time the user clicks on 'yes', you can push a custom value to form_counter just to add to it's length.